# Silence `gcloud auth activate-service-account`

Tags: gcloud, gcloud-cli

I'm using `gcloud auth activate-service-account` in a script to activate a service account. It outputs

```
Activated service account credentials for: [XXX@YYY.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
```

Is there a *flag* I can use to make the command not output anything? `--quiet` doesn't seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you need to use the `--no-user-output-enabled` flag.

```
gcloud --no-user-output-enabled auth activate-service-account --key-file=[service-account.json]
```

Official docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/):

> --user-output-enabled
>
> Print user intended output to the console. Overrides the default
>   core/user_output_enabled property value for this command invocation.
>   Use --no-user-output-enabled to disable.